# Micronaut not parsing user-defined object in POST call

Tags: java, rest, post, micronaut

```
@Controller("/v1")
@Secured(IS_AUTHENTICATED)
public interface OTPHandlerApi {
@Post(value = "/verify")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
HttpResponse<User> verify(@Body User body);
}
```

Created Micronaut POST call in above format but while parsing the object getting below error.

```
{"message":"Bad Request","_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Required Body [body] not specified","path":"/body"}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"v1/verify","templated":false}}}
```

Have tried with User defined object and also JsonObject from Micronaut, but getting same error, how to fix the same?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you add the same annotations to the implementation in the class that implements `OTPHandlerApi`?

Comment: Yes, having annotations inside interface or class have same . it is not working in both the places.